# Is it true that $T$ is orthogonal if and only if $T$ is isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products, orthogonality, vector-space-isomorphism

I want to prove the following:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space with inner product, then $T$ is orthogonal if and only $T$ is an isomorphism

I think the sufficiency could be true because $T$ is an isometry and then preserves its inner product, ($\langle \alpha \, ,  \,\beta \rangle = \langle T(\alpha) \, ,  \, T(\beta) \rangle$ so it follows that $T$ is injective, but I am not so sure if $T$ is surjective. 
Furtheremore, I do not know if the necessity it's true because I think I can find a counterexample, please help me!

Answer (score 9):

Take $T(x)=2x$ it is an ismorphism defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but it is not orthogonal.

Answer (score 3):

The backward direction of this statement is not true. An isomorphism (i.e. full-rank) linear transformation need not be an isometry.

Meanwhile, the forward direction of this statement is true. Let $A$ be the matrix representing $T$. Since $A$ has the property that $A^T A = I_n$ (where $\dim V = n$), and the rank of the product of two matrices is at most the rank of any of the two matrices multiplied, it follows that $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A^T) = n$, so $A$ is full rank. Hence, $T$ must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Is it correct the way I proved that T is injective?

Comment: I couldn’t quite follow your logic when you proved that. You’re going to have to elaborate a little more on why preserving the inner product means $T$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of $T$'s which are isomorphisms but not orthogonal.  To be precise, anything with nonzero determinant not equal to $\pm1$.